# Starting video recording immediately with AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture

I was trying to use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to record the device camera to a video file when my app starts. To my great frustration, I could not get it to work:

- I could view the video feed using a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` just fine, so my session was wired up properly.
- The file to which it would output did not already exist, and was in a writable directory.
- No errors were returned from API calls or via `AVCaptureSessionRuntimeError` notifications.
- My `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` methods were not called at all.

I tried sample code after sample code, and more maddeningly some of them seemed to actually work.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out that you cannot immediately start recording to the file like this:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession() 
session.beginConfiguration()
// add inputs, outputs
session.commitConfiguration()
videoFileOutput.startRecording(to: filePath, recordingDelegate: self)
```

This will **silently fail** and do nothing at all!

Instead, you need to wait for the session to start by registering for the `AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunning` notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sessionDidStartRunning), name: .AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunning, object: session)
```

You can implement this method as follows to start recording to a temporary file immediately after the session begins:

```
@objc
func sessionDidStartRunning(notification: NSNotification) {
    let session = notification.object as! AVCaptureSession
    for output in session.outputs {
        if let output = output as? AVCaptureMovieFileOutput {
            let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "recording.mov")
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath)
            output.startRecording(to: filePath, recordingDelegate: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 5h later: the clue here was correct. Starting the session DOES NOT mean it's started. `Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(startPushingData), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)` is actually a fix if you try to record screen.